# How to control phone via another an app

Tags: android

I've been trying to research this problem, but couldn't find much anywhere. I would like to make a Ruzzle Solver that plays Ruzzle for you.

I have the algorithm down to solve it, however, I don't know how to make an app that could control your phone while Ruzzle is on. I would like for it to play Ruzzle (like it should basically touch the screen and play it as a normal person would). Is this possible?

So to break it completely down, the user installs this app called "Ruzzle Solver". They open up Ruzzle Solver which is waiting in the background for Ruzzle to be loaded. Once Ruzzle is loaded, it takes over and plays it for you.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't fake touches between apps for security reasons.  If you're doing this hooked up to a PC for your own reasons you may be able to do it with Monkey.

Comment: That makes sense, but what if I just wanted it to work with my phone at least? Like could I break the security restrictions on my phone just so it could work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only possible using one of these two approaches:

- Root your device

  - Direct injection to /dev/input/eventX
  - Using InputManager.injectTouchEvent()
  - Using WindowManager.injectPointerEvent()
- Create an `AccessibilityService`. Notice that this is not guaranteed to work with all third-party apps.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm gonna try this out (may take some time), but ill def get back to accept answer once it works.